# convert a Date string without timezone in nodejs

Tags: node.js, date

I want to convert a string with just the date part, into a Date object in nodejs.
If I do this:

```
console.log('2010-10-05 ||', new Date('2010-10-05'));
console.log('2010-10-05 00:00:00 ||', new Date('2010-10-05 00:00:00'));
```

I obtain this in console:

```
2010-10-05 || Mon Oct 04 2010 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
2010-10-05 00:00:00 || Tue Oct 05 2010 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)
```

I don't want '2010-10-05' to be converted into '2010-10-04' because of my timezone.
My timezone is -0500 GMT.

How can I create a date by just providing the Date part without the gap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use zeros for hour, minute, second etc.

```
var date = '2010-10-05',
    arr  = date.split('-'),
    obj  = new Date(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

`Date.UTC` uses universal time instead of the local time, if that's what you need

```
Date.UTC(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2], 0, 0, 0, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log('2010-10-05 ||', new Date('2010-10-05' + ' UTC'))
console.log('2010-10-05 00:00:00 ||', new Date('2010-10-05 00:00:00' + ' UTC'))
```